# Apply $D(x,y)=(cx,cy)$ to the graph of $y=x^2$ and find the equation of the transformed graph.

Tags: quadratics, transformation

Hint: Let $u=cx$ and write $v=cx^2$ in terms of $u$.

---

What I think the answer is:

$y=x^2$ is the same as $(x, x^2)$ therefore, applying $D$ to the equation gives us $(cx, (cx)x=cx^2)$, that is, $y=cx^2$.

Answer (score -1):

According to the given hint, $x = \dfrac {u}{c}$.

Expressing v in terms of u, we should have $v = cx^2 = c (\dfrac {u}{c})^2 = \dfrac {u^2}{c}$. Then, $y = \dfrac {x^2}{c}$.

Comment: How do you go from $x=\frac{u}{c}$ and $v=\frac{u^2}{c}$ to just conclude $y=\frac{x^2}{c}$?

Comment: !) BY simple substitution. 2) To get the last equation, we have to consider v and u are just dummy variables.  Then, we can replace v by any name. In particular, I choose y.

Comment: Would like to know the reason of down-voting.